# Is it possible that in Java 7 (byte) ((char) ByteBuffer.get(X)) != ByteBuffer.get(X)?

Tags: java, java-7

The following code (this is a simplified version) used to run fine in jdk1.6 and now the assertion fails under jdk 1.7.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ...;
buffer.mark();
char c = (char) buffer.get();
buffer.reset();

switch(c) {
  ...
  case 'H':
    byte b = buffer.get(); 
    //Here I get -106 for b and 72 for (byte) c
    assert( b == ((byte) c) );
    break;
  ...
}
```

I read [oracle's compatibility page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html) and didn't find anything that would explain it. Maybe the 5- and 6- forms of utf8 but I don't think that is the case.
It could also be a race condition which I'm am still investigating, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask stackoverflow :-)

Comment: Why exactly do you think that chars are the same as bytes?

Comment: @BalusC I don't think they are the same.  This code is extracted from a legacy binary protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the behavior has not changed from 1.6 to 1.7 -- or, for that matter, from 1.0 to 1.7.

When you execute this line of code:

```
char c = (char) buffer.get();
```

You are effectively performing these steps:

1. Retrieve a `byte` value from the buffer
2. Convert that value into an `int`. Negative values are represented in twos-complement form.
3. Convert that integer into a `char`. This will simply mask the high-order two bytes, so a twos-complement integer will be a "large" character value.

In your case, what is probably happening is that the data format has changed, so that you're not at the expected point. Looking at the rest of the code, it seems that the "characters" that you're reading are supposed to be simple ASCII values.

Comment: note that I do a mark and reset on the buffer, so the second get I do is the same byte used in the switch.  Would you say this MUST be a race condition of some kind?

Comment: Without seeing all of the code, I do not have enough information to say "MUST" or "MAYBE." But if you have multiple threads accessing the same buffer, and you can guarantee that there are no other changes to `c` in the interim, it would seem likely that there's a race condition. Before jumping to that conclusion, I would probably replace the first `get()` with `byte b0 = buffer.get();` and `char c = (char)b0`. Then assert `b0 == b`.

Comment: That said, it does appear that *something* is changing either the position or contents of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

byte has a value range from -128 to +127 (8 bit signed)
char has a value range from 0 to +65535 (16 bit unsigned)
If you dont cast "c" to a char it works.

Comment: But has this changed from java 1.6 to java 1.7?  NOTE: a) it worked before on 1.6 and b) I know the char c == 'H'

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. char range is 0 to 65535 and byte range is -128 to 127. 
so

If you cast byte less then 0 to char you'll have wrong data

And if you cast smth out of -128 to 127 to byte you'll get wrong value

Comment: But has this changed from java 1.6 to java 1.7?  NOTE: a) it worked before on 1.6 and b) I know the char c == 'H'